# Rename files using batch file - original file name varies

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to rename a bunch of files that have random characters at the beginning of the file name.

For example I have these: `63edaa55dfh33_Section1.pdf`, `63edaa55dfh33_Section2.pdf`, `63edaa55dfh33_Section3.pdf`

I want to rename them to `Section1.pdf,` `Section2.pdf` and `Section3.pdf.`

The problem is the `"63edaa55dfh33_"` part may change so basically I want to remove everything up to and including the _ from every file.  I tried using rename `"*.pdf" "////*.pdf"` as a test but it didn't work.  The first 2 files were renamed properly with the first 4 characters removed but the 3rd file had the first 8 characters removed for some reason.

This solution may also not work because I don't always know the number of characters I want removed,that is why I want a way to say remove everything up to and including the _.

Comment: Take a look at the [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split the file names and use `_` as the delimiter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this on the command line in your pdf folder:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do @echo %a_%b %b
```

That will give you a feel for how it works.  Basically, the`"tokens=1,* delims=_"` causes the output from the `dir /B *.pdf` command to be split into pre and post delim parts (%a and %b respectively).  In a batch script you need to double all the percent symbols:

```
@for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B *.pdf') do @ren %%a_%%b %%b
```

Comment: Works perfectly for my needs.  Thank you for the help as well as the explanation.

Comment: @Stephan, thanks for the edit!  Don't know how I missed that obvious cut & paste error.

Comment: @catchingup2003, if this helped, please mark it as the answer, so others will be less likely to waste time on it.